# Swapping double pointers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

This is my code; i want to swap the names below. I am practicing this;

The error i am getting is

```
Segmentation fault
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
void nameSwap(char **wife[3],char **husband[3])
{
  int i;
  char **tmp[3];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {

  *tmp[i]=*wife[i];
  *wife[i] = *husband[i];
  *husband[i] = *tmp[i];
 } 

int main(int argc,char  *argv[])
{
char *name1[3]={"Chicago","University","Computer"};
char *name2[3]={"I","Love","Uchicago"};

int k;
char **p1[3];
char **p2[3];

for(k=0;k<3;k++)
{
*p1[k]=name1[k];
*p2[k]=name2[k];
}

for(k=0;k<3;k++)
{
printf("%s %s\n",*p1[k],*p2[k]);
}

nameSwap(&p1[3],&p2[3]);

for(k=0;k<3;k++)
{
printf("%s %s\n",*p1[k],*p2[k]);
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should add some more stars. Try become a six-star programmer.

Comment: @Mia `char **p1[3];` meant array of `char**`.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: There are far too many operators in your code: most `*`, `&` and `[]` should be removed.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Complete nonsense? It's actually perfectly valid C code, although the type should better be array of `const char *` and the name `name1` is misleading.

Comment: @Olaf that is not funny. Well Apparently we all learn from step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double pointer meant

case of `char **`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nameSwap(char ***wife, char ***husband){
    char **tmp;

    tmp = *wife;
    *wife = *husband;
    *husband = tmp;
}

int main(void){
    char *name1[3]={"Chicago","University","Computer"};
    char *name2[3]={"I","Love","Uchicago"};

    int k;
    char **p1;
    char **p2;

    p1 = name1;
    p2 = name2;

    for(k=0;k<3;k++){
        printf("%s %s\n", p1[k], p2[k]);
    }

    nameSwap(&p1, &p2);

    for(k=0;k<3;k++){
        printf("%s %s\n", p1[k], p2[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

case of pointer to `char *var_name[3]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nameSwap(char *(**wife)[3], char *(**husband)[3]){
    char *(*tmp)[3];

    tmp = *wife;
    *wife = *husband;
    *husband = tmp;
}

int main(void){
    char *name1[3]={"Chicago","University","Computer"};
    char *name2[3]={"I","Love","Uchicago"};

    int k;
    char *(*p1)[3];
    char *(*p2)[3];

    p1 = &name1;
    p2 = &name2;

    for(k=0;k<3;k++){
        printf("%s %s\n", (*p1)[k], (*p2)[k]);
    }

    nameSwap(&p1, &p2);

    for(k=0;k<3;k++){
        printf("%s %s\n", (*p1)[k], (*p2)[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the swapping function: it takes pointers to 2 arrays of 3 pointers to `char`.  It can be declared `void nameSwap(char *wife[3], char *husband[3])` but be aware that the array-like syntax is misleading and is actually equivalent to this: `void nameSwap(char *wife[], char *husband[])` or this: `void nameSwap(char **wife, char **husband)`.  In C, arrays of pointers to `char` are passed as pointers to pointers to `char`.

In order to perform the swap, only a single temporary variable is required since you swap only 2 pointers at a time.

Here is a corrected version, with the `[]` syntax to emphasize the fact that `wife` and `husband` point to arrays, not single pointers (just like `argv` in `main`):

```
void nameSwap(char *wife[], char *husband[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char *tmp = wife[i];
        wife[i] = husband[i];
        husband[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Then lets look at the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // These should really be const char *, but this is a minor problem
    char *name1[3] = { "Chicago", "University", "Computer" };
    char *name2[3] = { "I", "Love", "Uchicago" };

    int k;
    char *p1[3]; // removed the extra *. These are just arrays of pointers
    char *p2[3];

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        p1[k] = name1[k]; // removed the extra *, just assign array elements
        p2[k] = name2[k];
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", p1[k], p2[k]); // pass the pointers
    }

    nameSwap(p1, p2);  // simple pass the arrays
    // the nameSwap function receives pointers to the arrays,
    // just as if called as nameSwap(&p1[0], &p2[0]);         

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", p1[k], p2[k]); // should work now.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this explanation helps you understand better. Pointers and arrays are **the** tricky thing to grasp in the C language. The best way to get a hang of it is the same as for biking: get some help from a friend who already knows the art.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Highly appreciated.